# how can i overlay a simple svg file on the printpage of leaflet.browser.print

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, leaflet

I just wanna overlay a picture or a svg file on the print page, but not on the map itself.
Because if I do it on the map while the print is initializing there are a lot of problems with picture size, scaling and positioning of the Overlay.
So I thougt, it must be possible that I position the picture on the ready printpage without relation to the printed map.
I use Leaflet and node.js with js express.
At the moment I have leaflet.browser.print, but maybe another plugin is better for this usecase.

I tried to place the picture on these events of the plugin:

- browser-print-init
- browser-pre-print
- browser-print-start
- browser-print
  I didn't make it.
  Maybe the solution is in the css file?
  I don't know, need some help please.

I hope somebody has a solution how to do this.